# Is there a stand alone player for SoundCloud?

Tags: audio

Is there a stand alone player for SoundCloud?  To clarify my question, I am looking for something similar to Last.fm that would populate a tracklist based on incoming tracks or a list of favorites, run on the desktop and continue playing.

Comment: Can you specify for what OS if you want desktop? I think at least Windows, Mac, or Linux... and perhaps version (Windows 7, 8?), 32-bit vs 64-bit. For example, here is a SoundCloud desktop player for Mac: http://blog.soundcloud.com/2011/01/06/desktop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this, I learned of Chrome's create application shortcuts and have been using this in-lieu of a native app.  It's not a native app, but it get the job done.

A quick Google search also reveals a number of apps available in the Windows App store:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search#q=soundcloud&s=Store&ocid=appscle_search

Answer (score 2):

You can get a plugin (add-on) for standalone players like [Songbird](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1964), run searches and browse incoming tracks from followed artists. I guess this isn't standalone Soundcloud, but it is a desktop based application.

I suspect that you can probably find plugins for other similar players, I just use this one.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Update: This does not work with the latest version of SongBird (v2.0), so unfortunately this isn't going to help.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I hadn't noticed that it had disappeared (and wasn't at home when I wrote this). Damn!

Answer (score 1):

I think not.. but you can use your smartphone (android and iOS have a grat Soundcloud apps). Hope i helped a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CloudDeck](http://clouddeck.net/) with Adobe Air. Will work for Windows, Mac, or Linux this way. Looks like it has some track suggestion features, although I have not delved deeply in to the feature set.